# iptables: DNAT configuration FTP service

Tags: iptables, ftp, dnat

Hi have a FTP server behind a firewall and have problemi with DNAT configuration, internal server have ip 192.168.4.110:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 20 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.110:20
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 21 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.110:21
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1024:1048 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.110:1024-1048
```

And i have `nf_nat_ftp` and `nf_conntrack_ftp` modules loaded but not work, from FTP client i have a timeout

Comment: Typically there should be firewall rule accepting `related` packets in a stateful firewall i.e. `-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 0):

You quote the port range "1024-1048" in your existing config.  Are you implying that you've restricted your FTP server to only use these ports for data connections ?  If so, what you've done should work.

Check your machine is set to route packets by doing:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

You should get a "1" back if forwarding is enabled, which will be required for what you're trying to achieve.